# Group by month to plot on R with Highcharter

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I have the following dataset:

```
xdata <- seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"),as.Date("2020-12-31"), "days")
ydata <- c(1:366)
datamipo <- data.frame(xdata,ydata)
```

And I want to plot the data by month and plot using highcharter:

```
datamipo %>% 
  mutate(month = format(xdata,"%b")) %>%
  group_by(month) %>%
  summarise(total = sum(ydata)) %>%
  hchart(type = "line",
         hcaes(x=month, y=total))
```

But the x axis doesn't recognize the data as dates and put them in alphabetical order. Please, do you know how can I group the date to show the totals by month? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would think about saving this data differently and operate on the actual values. Here you can see an example of such a setting:

```
df <- data_frame(
  time = seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"), as.Date("2020-02-01"), by = 1),
  value = sample(1000:2000, size = 32),
  dt = datetime_to_timestamp(time)
)

hchart(df, "line",  hcaes(dt, value)) %>% 
  hc_xAxis(type = "datetime", dateTimeLabelFormats = list(day = '%d dayview', week = '%d weekview')) 

hchart(df, "line",  hcaes(dt, value)) %>% 
  hc_xAxis(type = "datetime", dateTimeLabelFormats = list(day = '%d of %b', week = '%d of %b'))
```